# How to create a CMakeLists.txt for a project containing CGAL and VTK libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, cgal

I've written a small programm for evaluating sientific data (3D surface mesh). I do all the geometric calculations with functions provided by the vtk library. The vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter is no robust and crashes randomly. So i decided to performe the boolean operations with functions of the cgal library (tested with some sample data -> no stability problems).

Now I want to merge this two projects together.

The vtk project CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(calcporosity)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(calcporosity MACOSX_BUNDLE calcporosity)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(calcporosity ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

else()
  target_link_libraries(calcporosity vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

The cgal project CMakeLists.txt:

> project( cgal_test )
>
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)
>   if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER
>   2.6)   if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION}"
>   VERSION_GREATER 2.8.3)
>       cmake_policy(VERSION 2.8.4)   else()
>       cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)   endif() endif()
>
> find_package(CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS Core )
>
> if ( CGAL_FOUND )
>
> include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )
>
> include( CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram )
>
> include_directories (BEFORE "../../include")
>
> include_directories (BEFORE "include")
>
> create_single_source_cgal_program( "cgaltest.cpp" )    else()
>
> message(STATUS "This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
>   endif()

I tried to merge this to files but I've failed. Could some give me a hint how to create a proper CMakeLists.txt for a project which utilizes both libraries.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

P.s.: I'm working on a Windows plattform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what needs to happen is that you need to provide include directories and link libraries from both of your dependencies to your executable.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

project( cgal_vtk_test )

# Find CGAL
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core) # If the dependency is required, use REQUIRED option - if it's not found CMake will issue an error
include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )

# Find VTK
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})


# Setup your executable
include_directories (BEFORE "../../include")
include_directories (BEFORE "include")

include( CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram )
create_single_source_cgal_program( "cgal_vtk_test.cpp" ) # This will create an executable target with name 'cgal_vtk_test'

# Add VTK link libraries to your executable target
target_link_libraries(cgal_vtk_test ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```